# Why do we write [1,1] in the minimize function

Tags: python

I am new to optimization Techniques and want to now best function for Getting optimum value for unconstrained multi-variables.

Why do we write `[1,1]` after `f` in `minimize` function??

```
{
def f(x):
    z=(x[0]**2)+(x[1]**2)
    d=x[0]+x[1]
    return z+d
from scipy.optimize import minimize
res=minimize(f,[1,1])
print res
}
```

I would appreciate help from anyone.

Comment: It's `x0 -> ndarray Initial guess` this [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is required argument (initial guess) according to http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html